# What Linux flavour to use for AMD GPU mining?

Tags: gpu-mining, linux

After many hours of struggle to install my `Sapphire RX 580` gpus on Ubuntu 16.04, I was frustrated when I realised [that](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Driver-Compatibility-Advisory-with-Ubuntu-16.04.2-and-16.04.3.aspx):

> Installation of AMDGPU-PRO drivers on Ubuntu 16.04.3 will likely
>   result in issues, such as black screen hang or defaulting to a lower
>   graphics mode without acceleration.  This also applies to Ubuntu
>   16.04.2 users who have been upgraded to 16.04.3.

I even tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 to avoid the issue, but it had the same issue.

So I had to switch to Windows 10 in order to make my rig of RX 580 gpus up and running.

However I really like to come back to Linux, as it is my preferred OS and, according to many, it offers better mining performance.

So I appreciate if you can tell me what flavors of Linux do not have issues with amdgpu-pro and can be used as the rig's OS.

Answer (score 3):

Arch Linux has an AUR that you could use ([link](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/opencl-amd/)) that allows you to [install](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMDGPU#AMDGPU_PRO) the proprietary OpenCL component you need for mining without the need for the closed-source *AMDGPU PRO* binary blob.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are attempting to mine over X? That sounds very inefficient, recently I purchased an RX 560 and I am mining steady at 400 h/s. Of course this is all done with minimal services and no GUI. After all, its for mining.

Use the amdgpu-pro drivers from http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Driver-for-Linux-Release-Notes.aspx on ubuntu 16.04 or later, follow the recipe and if you need to run X, comment out the following lines (I didn't care to have the added modules running)

[image]

Now if you struggle with commands and are new to Linux, stick with Windows 10.